# Suggestions for .NET Open Source FTP SDK/API

Tags: .net, ftp

Does anyone have a suggestion for a good open source FTP SDK/API for .NET?  or is the one built into the framework the best?

Comment: I'm looking for something that makes it easy to connect to FTP servers supporting protocols SFTP and FTP SSL and certificate authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Something like Alex FTPS Client? Like @Adam Houldsworth pointed out, only saying "best" is not enough for a good question.

http://ftps.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a healthy list of FTP libraries for .NET: http://csharp-source.net/open-source/network-clients (among other network client libraries).

Answer (score 0):

try this open source ftp library its easy to use and written in a simple manner so that it can be modified as per usage.

[**t-ftp library**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/343913/Simple-FTP-library-in-Csharp)